# cp and dd stuck when writing ISO image to USB flash drive

Tags: linux, usb, dd, cp

I have a hybrid ISO image (Debian netinst, size is around 473MB) which I tried to write to a USB flash drive on my Debian system. When I tried to do this with any of the following commands (`sdX` is the device corresponding to the flash drive):

```
$ cp image.iso /dev/sdX
$ dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress
```

then the command got stuck and didn't finish, even after 10-15 minutes of waiting (and the flash drive's LED was constantly blinking, as if data were still being written; for other USB drives/pendrives which I had tried in the past it would normally finish in around 1 minute or less). Moreover, the cp/dd process could not be stopped with `CTRL-C`, nor even with `kill -9` - I had to remove the flash drive from the USB port to stop the copy process. (I suspect the data sent by cp/dd were cached and the kernel was waiting until the flash drive confirmed that all the data were finally written).

I checked `dmesg` output and didn't find any write errors there, except for those that occurred around the time when I removed the flash drive from the USB port.

After that, I created a single exFAT partition on the same flash drive (allocating for it all space on the flash drive, so that it also contained the area where the ISO image would have been written by cp/dd commands), mounted it and copied the ISO image as a regular file there, just to check if the same thing would happen. It took around 2 minutes (it turned out this flash drive has rather slow write speed), but it finished.

I also checked `lsusb` to see if the flash drive identifies itself in some suspicious way, but it presented itself simply as "USB storage".

What could be the reason that the copy operation gets stuck when writing directly to the device (or, at least, is incredibly slow) but is working fine when writing to a partition? Could the flash drive be damaged or have some write protection put on some of the first blocks? Or could it be a fake/suspicious flash drive and better to avoid it?

Comment: You can use `iostat` (install what provides it if needed) to see if there's still ongoing writing activity (if it blinks, chances are writes are happening). Don't remove an USB drive while it's being written to: best way to damage it.

Comment: @A.B thank you for you suggestion! For `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress` command, iostat showed a short 20MB/s burst at the beginning of transfer, followed by occassional short transfers measured in hundreds of kBs, sometimes a few MBs, per second. I interrupted the transfer after 3 minutes.

What worked for me was adding `oflag=direct` option to `dd` command: `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M oflag=direct status=progress`. This time, transfer completed after 86 seconds (avg. speed 5.7 MB/s), and iostat showed a few 20MB/s bursts separated with a few-second pauses.

Comment: What is probably worth noting: when I plug the flash drive in, `dmesg` reports `[sdX] No Caching mode page found [sdX] Assuming drive cache: write through`. I think the 20MB/s bursts with a few-second pauses that I observed with `oflag=direct` option (and only very rarely without `oflag=direct`) might be caused by caching performed by the flash drive itself. Perhaps caching done by Linux (without `oflag=direct` option) and caching done by the flash drive don't play nice with each other for some reason, although I have no idea why.

Comment: I forgot to mention that without `oflag=direct` option, the flash drive's LED was blinking even when `iostat` was reporting no writing for the flash drive (during few-second breaks between short, hundred-KB-or-a-few-MB/s bursts). Perhaps the drive was writing the data that it had still stored in its internal cache...

Comment: Sounds like synch is slow. (You should do `sync` after `dd` to ensure all is actually written to the disk). You could add something like `conv=fsync`. You could also test by something like `<file sudo tee /dev/sdX >/dev/null` followed by `sync` to check.

Comment: As for `kill -9` `dd` was likely waiting for some kernel response by a call that is not interruptible. (Perhaps it was synching with `fdatasync`? You can see the *Dirty* entry in `/proc/meminfo` (Was likly slowly declining).

Comment: You could also compare after by e.g. `head -c $(stat -c '%s' image.iso) /dev/sdX | sha256sum` vs `sha256sum image.iso`

Comment: Are you aware that Linux uses buffered writes to the device? So to compare `dd` with a filesystem, `sync` the dirty buffers. It could take a while. Maybe your stick is slow or close to dying.